# SSRS An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Getting this error message in report builder when trying to upload stored procedure. Ran in sql without errors. The person who made this report had just created 5 queries instead of a stored procedure when creating it so I'm trying to put it into one dataset so that I can run it based off of location.

This is what I ran:

```
(
@Location varchar(100), 
@BeginDate datetime,
@EndDate datetime
)
as 
BEGIN

select 
  cl.ClientCode,
  icr.LocationUnit,
  icr.InfectionCLass,
  icr.ID,
  icr.IfYesDiagnosis,
  icr.VHRStartDate,
  icr.DiagnosisDate,
  icr.ReferedtoDoc,
  icr.AntibioticsReq,
  icr.ReferredHealthDept,
  mer.ID,
  mer.Medication,
  mer.ErrorType,
  mer.ErrorDate,
  mer.StaffResponsible,
  mer.AdverseDrugEvent,
  s.FirstName as StaffFirst,
  s.LastName as StaffLast,
  mer.VHRStartDate,
  adr.LocationUnit,
  adr.Client,
  adr.ID,
  adr.NotifiedMD,
  adr.ReactionDescrip,
  adr.ActionTaken,
  adr.ReactionSeverity,
  adr.Staff,
  adr.VHRStartDate,
  adr.Outcome,
  ts.LocationUnit,
  ts.DateNeeded,
  ts.VHRStartDate,
  ts.Task,
  ts.ID
FROM
   dbo.Clients as cl
INNER JOIN dbo.SCS_InfectionControlReport as icr
    ON cl.id = icr.Client
and cast(icr.VHRStartDate as DATE) between cast(@BeginDate as DATE) and cast(@EndDate as DATE)
INNER JOIN dbo.SCS_MedErrorReport as mer
    ON cl.id = mer.Client
join dbo.staff as s on s.id = mer.StaffResponsible
and cast(mer.VHRStartDate as DATE) between cast(@BeginDate as DATE) and cast(@EndDate as DATE)
INNER JOIN dbo.SCS_AdverseDrugReaction as adr
    ON cl.id = adr.Client
join dbo.staff as a on a.id = adr.Staff
and cast(adr.VHRStartDate as DATE) between cast(@BeginDate as DATE) and cast(@EndDate as DATE)
INNER JOIN dbo.SCS_TaskNeeds as ts
    ON cl.id = ts.Client
WHERE
  ts.Task =  N'Dietary Consult' OR ts.Task = N'TB Test' 
and cast(ts.VHRStartDate as DATE) between cast(@BeginDate as DATE) and cast(@EndDate as DATE)
```

I didn't know if it has something to do with the old report or what I wrote?

Comment: Thanks! That could be it but I don't know of a way to check it. Our report server is on saas so I can't delete or open files with another program. Do you know if there is another way?

Comment: Or could it be something else? Those reports were deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your dataset query has non-unique columns. For example, ID is output 4 times. When the query is parsed by SSRS it adds fields to the dataset's field collection. The error is trying to tell you it already had a field called 'ID'.

If you need all the ID columns you can simply alias them e.g. `icr.ID as [icrID],`  etc...